# babel transpile to es2016 (for async await) for node v6

Tags: babeljs

How can babel transpile async await functionality to ES2015 or ES6

if yes, please let me know the commands / options to pass to babel /  .babelrc file to set ?

> > http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015

But i was looking for something which would transpile to ES15 not js 5. which means "let  a =100;" should not transformed to "var a =100;"  but features *after* ES15 will be transpiled to ES15; like async.

Comment: You can try it out yourself at http://babeljs.io/repl/#?evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Cstage-0&code=

Comment: awesome thanks, will be setting that in .babelrc right; But i was looking for something which would transpile to ES15 not js 5. which means "let  a =100;" should not transformed to "var a =100;"  but features after ES15 will be transpiled to ES15.

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/marten-de-vries/kneden

Comment: @Artem,, thanks,, great pointers, but link says : "WARNING: Kneden is usable, but it's also not complete yet."